# Error with loops in R: Error "object not found"

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I have panel data with years from 2005 to 2015 and sectors from 1 to 33 (excluding 2, 4 and 31). I would like to run some loops and save the output for each year-sector combination separately. This is my code:

```
    for (i in 2005:2015){

  ntm_data <-subset(ntm_data_wip, StartDate <=i & EndDate >i)
  
for(s in c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32,  33)){
  
  ntm_data <-subset(ntm_data, ISIC4==s)
  
# Once the data is loaded, I exclude NTM codes which are missing. 
# I only need the reporter, NTM code and product codes (HS 6-digit codes).
ntm_data <- ntm_data[!is.na(ntm_data$ntmcode)&ntm_data$ntmcode!="",]
ntm_data <- ntm_data[,c("reporter", "ntmcode", "hs6")]

# I group the data by reporter, NTM and product code (hs6) and count the number of combinations in a new variable called count.
ntm_data <- ntm_data %>% group_by(reporter, ntmcode, hs6) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
head(ntm_data)

# I prepare the regulatory matrix by creating a list of countries for which I want the regulatory distance.  The 
# regulatory matrix shows the distance between two countries and has as column and row names the ISO3 codes of the countries.
# As specified above, I am interested in having the analysis for all available countries. 
avail_iso3s <- unique(ntm_data$reporter)

# I create an empty regulatory distance matrix. For column size I use the length of avail_iso3s and add 1 for the reporter column.
# I populate the column names with reporter and the ISO3 codes with the option dimnames.
regulatory_distance_matrix <- data.frame(matrix(vector(),0,length(avail_iso3s)+1,
                                                dimnames = list(c(), c("reporter", avail_iso3s )
                                                )),
                                         stringsAsFactors=F)


#' Now I can move on to calculating the regulatory distance formula in page 3 of "DEEP REGIONAL INTEGRATION AND NON-TARIFF MEASURES:A METHODOLOGY FOR DATA ANALYSIS (2015)" . 
#' As N is a constant, I start with calculating it outside of the loop
N <- ntm_data %>% group_by(ntmcode, hs6) %>% count()
N <- nrow(N)

# I now fill in the regulatory distance matrix with values

for (g in 1:length(avail_iso3s)){
  country_a <- ntm_data[ntm_data$reporter==avail_iso3s[g],c("ntmcode", "hs6")]
  country_a$country_a <- 1
  regulatory_distance_matrix[g,"reporter"] <- avail_iso3s[g]
  
  for (k in 1:length(avail_iso3s)){
    
    if (!is.na(regulatory_distance_matrix[k,avail_iso3s[g]])){next }
    
    country_b <- ntm_data[ntm_data$reporter==avail_iso3s[k],c("ntmcode", "hs6")]
    country_b$country_b <- 1
    merged <- merge(country_a, country_b, by=c("ntmcode", "hs6"), all = TRUE)
    merged[is.na(merged)] <- 0
    merged$abs_diff <- abs(merged$country_a-merged$country_b)
    rd <- sum(merged$abs_diff)/N
    regulatory_distance_matrix[g,avail_iso3s[k]] <- rd
    
  }
}

# Now I fill in the missing values and create a Stata dta.file.
for (g in 1:length(avail_iso3s)){
  for (k in 1:length(avail_iso3s)){
    if (is.na(regulatory_distance_matrix[k,avail_iso3s[g]])){
      regulatory_distance_matrix[k,avail_iso3s[g]] <- regulatory_distance_matrix[g,avail_iso3s[k]]
    }
  }
}


regulatory_distance_matrix$year <-i
regulatory_distance_matrix$ISIC4 <-s

write.dta(regulatory_distance_matrix, paste0("C:/Users/Utente/Desktop/Master's thesis/Thesis analysis/- RD construction/Binary sectoral RD/regulatory_distance_matrix_",i,"_",s,".dta"))
} 
}
```

However, after the first file (regulatory_distance_matrix_",i,"_",s,".dta") is correctly created, I get the following error during the creation of the second file:

```
 Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) : oggetto "ISIC4" non trovato
```

Does someone how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

```
> dput(head(ntm_data_wip))
structure(list(reporter = c("TUR", "ARG", "BRA", "CHN", "USA", 
"EUN"), Reporter_ISO_N = c("792", "032", "076", "156", "842", 
"918"), hs6 = c("910610", "851679", "040221", "620449", "021012", 
"284990"), ntmcode = c("B31", "A11", "B33", "B83", "A83", "B33"
), partner = c("TON", "WLD", "WLD", "IRN", "VAT", "WLD"), Partner_ISO_N = c("776", 
"000", "000", "364", "336", "000"), nbr = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), Year = c(2016L, 2014L, 2013L, 2016L, 2017L, 2011L), NTMNomenclature = c("M4", 
"M4", "M4", "M4", "M4", "M4"), NomenCode = c("H4", "H4", "H4", 
"H4", "H4", "H3"), Dataset_id = c(161L, 174L, 174L, 131L, 179L, 
111L), ntm_1_digit = c("B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B"), StartDate = c(2015L, 
2006L, 2008L, 2011L, 1992L, 2009L), EndDate = c(9999L, 9999L, 
9999L, 9999L, 9999L, 2011L), new_ISIC4 = c("32", "28", "10", 
"13", "10", "19"), ISIC4 = c(32L, 28L, 10L, 13L, 10L, 19L)), datalabel = "", time.stamp = "31 Jul 2021 11:34", formats = c("%9s", 
"%9s", "%9s", "%9s", "%9s", "%9s", "%9.0g", "%12.0g", "%9s", 
"%9s", "%12.0g", "%9s", "%10.0g", "%10.0g", "%9s", "%10.0g"), types = c(3L, 
3L, 6L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 65530L, 65529L, 2L, 3L, 65529L, 1L, 65529L, 
65529L, 2L, 65530L), val.labels = structure(c("", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""), .Names = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")), var.labels = c("", 
"", "", "", "", "", "Number of NTM, distinct codes", "", "", 
"", "", "", "(min) StartDate", "(max) EndDate", "", ""), version = 118L, label.table = list(), expansion.fields = list(
    c("ISIC4", "destring", "Characters removed were:"), c("ISIC4", 
    "destring_cmd", "destring new_ISIC4, gen(ISIC4)")), byteorder = "LSF", orig.dim = c(6953474L, 
16L), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please share a part of `ntm_data_wip` usung `dput(head(ntm_data_wip))`. Edit your question and put the `structure()`output of `dput` there.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer Martin Gal! I shared the structure of the output as you asked and I also added the code for the whole loop. Please tell me if there is anything I can do to help understand better!

Comment: Your sample data does not provide enough information to diagnose the problem. One issue might be that your inner loop can iterate through values of ISIC4 that may not exist in the subset created in the outer loop, thus creating empty data. Try changing the inner loop to `for (s in unique(ntm_data$ISIC4))`

Comment: Thank you very much @jdobres for your suggestion! Unfortunately, the error still persists. I have also noticed two further things that may be useful to solve the problem:

1. When I try the loop without the part related to the sector, namely  
`for(s in c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32,  33)){
  
  ntm_data <-subset(ntm_data, ISIC4==s)
.......
regulatory_distance_matrix$ISIC4 <-s`
It works well.

2. If I manually run the analysis, it does yield any problem.

Comment: If `unique(ntm_data$ISIC4))` as proposed by @jdobres is not option for you, cou could go with `(1:33)[-c(2,4,31)]` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

The issue is that the inner loop of `for (s in c(...)) {...}` uses `ntm_data` which overwrites itself within the inner loop. So in the first pass, `ntm_data$ICIS4` is a column. Plus, since we are subsetting, we don’t want subsequent iterations having been filtered based on the previous `s`.

Here's a snippet of the top of the beginning code with a new object at the start of the outer loop.:

```
library(dplyr)
for (i in 2005:2015){
   ## CHANGED - make a different object for the inner loop to subset from
  ntm_data_years <-subset(ntm_data_wip, StartDate <=i & EndDate >i) 
  
  for(s in c(1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 32,  33)){
    ntm_data <-subset(ntm_data_years, ISIC4==s) ## CHANGED to subset(ntm_data_years, ...)
    
    ntm_data <- ntm_data[!is.na(ntm_data$ntmcode)&ntm_data$ntmcode!="",]
    ntm_data <- ntm_data[,c("reporter", "ntmcode", "hs6")] ## This is the line that removes ISIC4 from the data frame
    
... 
}
```